# Handling CSP with Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, content-security-policy

we are using Vue js but when we want to add the **CSP headers** we cant use without using `unsafe-eval` in the CSP header.

**we are using VUE `<templates>` for the components.**

I tried to change the version to CSP compatible version as specified in the VUE doc. but not sure how to proceed with the CSP and VUE. I tried to check a lot of articles but nothing helped me out.

I tried with vue@csp but its throwing version mismatch of `VUE` and `vue-template-compiler` when I tried to bundle the files.

I am not sure how should I have to remove the template from the components or I can compile the template with the csp version.

Can someone please help how I can proceed with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Related https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/616

Comment: On theory CSP settings can live in a HTML meta tag - but it is far better to generate them server-side as HTTP header (in which case they are completely unrelated to Vue or React or Angular). For example, if your Vue application is deployed on Netlify - you can put your CSP headers into `_headers` file inside the `public` folder of your project.